# How to draw a line plot when dates are in two different columns?

Tags: r, ggplot2, line-plot

Lets say I have the following dataset:

```
dt <- data.frame(id= c(1),
                 parameter= c("a","b","c"),
                 start_day = c(1,8,4),
                 end_day = c(16,NA,30))
```

[image]

I want to create a type of line chart such that "**parameter**" column is my **y-axis** and both ("**start_day**" and "**end_day**") are on my **x-axis**.

Alo, if both "start_day" and "end_day" have values, then they be connected through a line. In case there is no "end_day"  (like for parameter "b") then the "start_day" be connected to an arrow indicating there is no "end_day" for that parameter. (I know it sound confusing but I will make an example to clarify)

I know that for [line chart](https://r-graph-gallery.com/line-plot.html) I need to have all the dates in one column. But in my data frame I have two separate columns (start and end dates).
So I think line chart is not the proper tool for this case and instead I tried **swimmer_points_from_lines** and **swimmer_arrows**.

I added a new column named "**cont**" to be used in swimmer_arrows.

```
dt$cont <- with(dt, ifelse(end_day > 0 ,1, 0))

ggplot(data = dt)+
  swimmer_points_from_lines(df= dt, 
                            id="parameter", 
                            start= "start_day",
                            end="end_day")+
  swimmer_arrows(df_arrows = dt,
                 id="parameter",
                 arrow_start = "start_day",
                 cont = "cont")+
  coord_flip()
```

The outcome is as follow:
[image]

What I am looking for at this point is to find a way to **draw a line** **between "start_day" and "end_day"** (given both end and start day exist). And **if there is no "end_day"** I want **an arrow indicates that there is no end date** (the exact opposite of what I am getting right now).

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw a line between points where the values are in separate columns you could use `geom_segment`. To add an arrow to obs with no end date one option would be to split your data into two parts, one with non-missing and one with missing end-dates, and use two `geom_segment`s:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dt, aes(y = parameter)) + 
  geom_segment(data = ~subset(.x, !is.na(end_day)), aes(x = start_day, xend = end_day, yend = parameter)) +
  geom_segment(data = ~subset(.x, is.na(end_day)), aes(x = start_day, xend = start_day + 1, yend = parameter), 
               arrow = arrow(type = "closed", length = unit(0.1, "inches"))) +
  geom_point(aes(x = start_day, shape = "start_day"), size = 3, color = "red") +
  geom_point(aes(x = end_day, shape = "end_day"), size = 3, color = "red") +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(16, 17))
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

Comment: I just realized that I confused color and shape which I just fixed. Now the right shapes are displayed in the legend while the color is set as an argument.